# Android - How to tell in ACRA whether the error happened on the simularor?

Tags: android, acra

I am getting some strange reports about errors and I am wondering whether it happened during testing.

Where do I look in my ACRA reports to see whether the device was the simulator?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the PHONE_MODEL and PRODUCT columns, should be set to 'google_sdk' for the emulator. Check the BUILD column for more details.